# Train tesseract to one specific font

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract to OCR text from a screen-**scraper** application.
The *only* font used is the Segoe UI 8 CLEARTYPE QUALITY (see image below).
At this moment tesseract is doing a poor job, mixing Z and 2, 0 and o and so on.

I've tried to scale up the text image (no improvements). Looking at eng.traineddata I can see that tesseract is not trained with Segoe UI 8 CLEARTYPE QUALITY.

**Question**: How can I train tesseract with a new font *and* specify that only that font should be used?

[image]

Comment: You got a solution to this?

Comment: @Pranav, no but I have started a bounty. Did you find a solution? Please share if you did :-)

Comment: Here is a good guide: https://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/

Comment: @Vingtoft . Yes. I used learning to teach the OCR engine for different types of fonts. It works perfect for me. I have converted the images into box files and then used a box file to train.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide **an example of your effort**. My goal is to help you reach your goal, not to do the work for you.

This is quite a common problem and lots of people have solved this, some more efficiently than others. You can use the tools that they have created.

An example

- code: https://github.com/ValYouW/ml-ocr-tool
- video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uc05vyjVuw&t=631s
  [image: ocr]

There are multiple others, some of them do just typefaces and are optimized for that. It might be something that is more impactful for you. For example:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_1-hGsXxy8 
  [image]

There are other examples, but most of them use image magic and other tools to improve the initial input data quality so that the OCR tool does its best. Personally, I wrote efficient c# GDI transformations to manipulate the input data before I run Tesseract on it.